# jQuery date picker: limit certain months and limit current month upcoming days

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

i am trying to reject current month upcoming days. that is i want to show only upto current day date. example show only upto 13/9/2013. how to do that in jquery. show me an example code for that.also the date picker show only past three month dates.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=txtFrmdate.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
            showsTime: true,
            ifFormat: "%d/%m/%y %H:%M",
            daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
            align: "BR",
            electric: false,
            singleClick: false,
            displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
            button: ".next()"
        });
    });
```

Comment: You have to show your own code/effort.

Comment: Please read the [jQuery API documentation for datepicker min/max](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max) **PS** That looks nothing like the jQueryUI Datepicker widget. Where did you find this `.dynDateTime()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -"-3M", maxDate: "+0D" });
```

Where "-3M" is "three months in the past" and "+0D" is "no dates in the future".

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: "-3M", maxDate: "+0D" });
});
```

So your code would become:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=txtFrmdate.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
        showsTime: true,
        ifFormat: "%d/%m/%y %H:%M",
        daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
        align: "BR",
        electric: false,
        singleClick: false,
        displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
        button: ".next()",
        minDate: "-3M", 
        maxDate: "+0D"

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Some example code there for you. As well as the full API.